# Permission denied after page refresh in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to implement authentication in vuejs 3.  I'm django and django as a backend and simple jwt for generating token. Every things is working fine.  Generated token are in this format.
[image]

And here is my auth store , by the way I'm using axios and vuex

```
import axios from "axios";
import { API_ENDPOINTS } from "../../constants/API";

const authStore = {
  state: {
    status: "",
    access_token: localStorage.getItem("access_token") || "",
    refresh_token: localStorage.getItem("refresh_token") || "",
  },
  mutations: {
    auth_request(state) {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    auth_success(state, access_token, refresh_token, user) {
      state.status = "success";
      state.access_token = access_token;
      state.refresh_token = refresh_token;
      state.user = user;
    },
    auth_error(state) {
      state.status = "error";
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.status = "";
      state.access_token = "";
      state.refresh_token = "";
    },
  },
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, user) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit("auth_request");
        axios({
          url: API_ENDPOINTS.CREATE_TOKEN,
          data: user,
          method: "POST",
        })
          .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
            const access_token = resp.data.access;
            const refresh_token = resp.data.refresh;
            const user = resp.data.user;
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
            localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", refresh_token);
            axios.defaults.headers.common[
              "Authorization"
            ] = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
            commit("auth_success", access_token, refresh_token, user);
            resolve(resp);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            commit("auth_error");
            localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
            localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit("logout");
        localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
        localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
        resolve();
      });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: (state) => !!state.access_token,
    authStatus: (state) => state.status,
  },
};

export default authStore;
```

Above code is working fine, only issue is that whenever I refresh my page, I can't able to perform any operation, Like get or post.

Even token is available in localstorage.

Note:-
I think I'm missing some things like refresh token, I think i need to use refresh token, but I've no any idea that how can i use refresh token if refresh token is problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.defaults.headers.common[
              "Authorization"
            ] = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
```

This code is noly called when user login, so maybe you should call it when the token is availble at localstorage.